# What is the definition of a selective survey?

Tags: research-process, methodology

Is it similar to a narrative review? I’m looking at a survey of a sub-field of computer science and it’s defined as a ‘selective survey’ however I can’t find a definition of this anywhere.

Comment: Link to paper if of further help: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.215.1091&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Selective is an adjective, and here it means not everything is surveyed, emphasizing that is it not meant to be comprehensive.